# Объединение JSON файлов

Tags: c#, json

Имеется 3 файла JSON, с одной структурой(cм. ниже)

1 файл

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Info2": "Name",
    "Info3": "Sername",
    "Age": 16
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Info2": "Name2",
    "Info3": "Sername2",
    "Age": 20
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Info2": "Name3",
    "Info3": "Sername3",
    "Age": 10
  }
]
```

2 файл

```
[
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Info2": "Name",
        "Info3": "Sername",
        "Age": 17
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Info2": "Name2",
        "Info3": "Sername2",
        "Age": 21
      },
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "Info2": "Name3",
        "Info3": "Sername3",
        "Age": 11
      }
    ]
```

3 файл

```
[
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Info2": "Name",
        "Info3": "Sername",
        "Age": 18
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Info2": "Name2",
        "Info3": "Sername2",
        "Age": 22
      },
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "Info2": "Name3",
        "Info3": "Sername3",
        "Age": 12
      }
    ]
```

С помощью этого кода я получаю список из одого фала:

```
var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Person>>(File.ReadAllText("file1.json", Encoding.UTF8));
```

Возможно ли объединить эти 3 файла в один, что бы в итоге получали массив `file1, file2, file3`, из которого выходили остальные данные?

UPD::
Удалось объединить с помощью CompositeCollection:

```
CompositeCollection cc = new CompositeCollection();
            cc.Add(obj1);
            cc.Add(obj2);
            cc.Add(obj3);
```

Comment: Десереализуйте в 3 списка `List<Person>`, затем соедините все списки в один `list1.AddRange(list2)`, затем сереализуйте получившийся спискок обратно в json.

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Что именно не получается?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Конкретно не понимаю как их объеденить, что бы итог был в ObservalCollection, и объеденить структурировано, если делать через AddRange, оно просто добавит всё в конец

Comment: А надо было не в конец? В вопросе это не указано.

Comment: @aepot "Возможно ли объединить эти 3 файла в один, что бы в итоге получали массив file1, file2, file3, из которого выходили остальные данные?"
Читайте пожалуйста внимательнее

Comment: К сожалению, мен до сих пор не понятно, что это значит, могу только догадываться. Перечитал раз 5, список списков `List<List<Person>>`? Окей, замените `List` на `ObservableCollection`, смысл не поменяется.

Comment: ObservalCollection не имеет AddRange, и ответ я написал ниже.

Answer (score 2):

```csharp
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Person>> data = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Person>>();
string[] files = new string[] { "file1.json", "file2.json", "file3.json" };
foreach (string file in files)
{
    data.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Person>>(File.ReadAllText(file)));
}
```

`Encoding.UTF8` - `ReadAllText` определит кодировку автоматически, поэтому нет нужды ее явно указывать.

Comment: С каких пор по умолчанию UTF8?

Comment: @Qwertiy ок, исправил.

Comment: Что-то тоже не уверен.

Comment: Кстати, даже если пытается угадать, такое угадывание - зло. Если известна кодировка, то лучше её указать.

Comment: @Qwertiy судя по докам `ReadAllText`, там все угадывание сводится к определению, UTF-8 или UTF32. И у меня около 100 000 пользователей у одного проекта, который читает и пишет файлы таким образом, и за последние 5 лет пока никто не жаловался. Не надо придавать сомнению то, что проверено и исправно работает. Весь вопрос в доверии к логике, вшитой в .NET, я стараюсь максимально на дефолтных значениях сидеть.

Comment: Там сказано, определение на основе BOM. Сейчас большинство файлов в UTF8 без BOM.

Comment: @Qwertiy чтобы авторитетно в этом разобраться, надо лезть в сорцы, а у меня пока нет возможности и желания это делать прямо сейчас, поэтому считаю ваше замечание валидным. Спасибо большое, что предупредили, я обязательно в этом когда-нибудь разберусь. :)

Answer (score -1):

Удалось объединить объекты ObservalCollection с помощью CompositeCollection

```
CompositeCollection cc = new CompositeCollection();
            cc.Add(obj1);
            cc.Add(obj2);
            cc.Add(obj3);
```